# Facebook Authentication login

Tags: facebook, authentication, web

i have build a web app with facebook,goolge,instagram login and everything is working ok but today It happened an error.

When someone tried to login in my web app with facebook account it redirect to homepage and show me white screen of my home page.

Please any help!!!tr

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *localhost* is not a valid redirect uri.
 Please try : http://localhost/redirect.php 
 and than put your redirect handler processing code there.